# Trouble getting Mongo DB to set up using npm on windows 7... any ideas?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, npm

I'm having trouble getting mongodb and mongoose to install with npm. Any advice would be much appreciated! I saw an earlier post where they said to clear the cache and update - this has been done but still the same problem... below is the error for mongo db install but it's almost exactly the same for mongoose

various get from server logs...

```
> mongodb@0.9.9-2 install C:\Users\petrov\Desktop\nodejs\node_modules\mongodb
> node install.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! error installing mongodb@0.9.9-2

npm ERR! mongodb@0.9.9-2 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the mongodb@0.9.9-2 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the mongodb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node install.js
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls mongodb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Users\\petrov\\Desktop\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\petrov\\Desktop\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "mongodb"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\petrov\Desktop\nodejs
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.10
npm ERR! npm -v 1.1.0-3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! message mongodb@0.9.9-2 install: `node install.js`
npm ERR! message `cmd "/c" "node install.js"` failed with 1
npm ERR! errno {}
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\petrov\Desktop\nodejs\npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the path where node is installed or run the command from the same directory where you installed the node.

Comment: thanks! i ran the command from the node installation directory from the beginning...

Comment: make sure node is in you windows path as I think npm shells out so if  it's not in PATH it won't be able to find it.

Answer (score 2):

try npm -dd install mongodb

it might work for you. there seems to be a bug in npm

Comment: thanks for your advice! tried that but there is still the same problem - it seems the install script always bugs at the moment it call 'node install.js' from inside the shell. it says 'node' is not recognized.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are still running into this issue, I solved it by adding the nodejs  installation path (`C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\` for me) to my local PATH environment variable.